# Agregar dados por mês usando mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express.js, mongoose

Olá! Preciso agregar dados por mês para usar depois para fazer gráficos. Estou usando o Mongoose como ODM e o seguinte esquema:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('atendimento', {
    id: String,
    id_atendimento: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    id_cliente: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    id_user: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    user_nome: String,
    cliente_nome: String,
    id_atendente: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    atendente_nome: String,
    atendente_imagem: String,
    setor: Number,
    descricao: String,
    status: String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    inicio: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    fim: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    update: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

Preciso de todos os atendimentos por mês, estava dando uma olhdaa e o que eu fiz na rota que vai ter os dados foi o seguinte:

```
     atendimentos.aggregate({
       $group: {
         _id: {
             year: {$year: "$date"},
             month: {$month: "$date"},
             day: {$dayOfMonth: "$date"}

         },
         total: {$sum: 1}
       }

    });
```

Não sei se está correto mas não tive nenhum erro, mas também não mostrou nada. Agradeço quem puder me ajudar.

Comment: Então mas o seu banco não tem os campos year, month e day. Não tem como vc agrupar assim, experimenta colocar o campo date. Aqui tem uns [exemplos](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-aggregate-and-group-example/)

Comment: Opa, valeu pela resposta! Já arrumei aqui e consegui os dados da maneira que eu queria, mas obrigado de qualquer forma

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
collection.aggregate([
               { $project:
                       { _id: "$month",
                         year: {$year: "$date" },
                           month: { $month: "$date"},
                           amount: 1
                       }
               },
               { $group:
                       { _id: { year: "$year", month: ("$month")},
                           sum: { $sum: 1}
                       }
           }]).exec(function(error, items){
                if(error){return next(error);}

                console.log(items);
           });
```